# Name of this blanking plug

Tags: cables, cable-management

I am trying to find this blanking plug, for a cable outside. It's flat and plastic

[image]

I found this on eBay however it has a bit that sticks out for the cable however I don't need the bit that sticks into the hole and guides the cable in.

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/x5-White-Plastic-Hole-Tidy-Wall-Grommet-Cover-Cable-Entry-Exit-CCTV-SKY-VIRGIN-/264463777668

Does that bit come off? Or is there another name for this blanking plug/grommet with just the flat cover?

Comment: are you saying that you are looking for a round plastic disk with an oval hole in the middle?

Comment: _"I don't need the bit that sticks into the hole and guides the cable in"_ -- why not? how do you expect to secure the grommet to the wall otherwise? Your question is not clear. :(

Comment: The one on the wall doesnt have that part, so guessing its sold without it. I dont need it as I cant rewire the whole thing - I just need to get it cut it around it covered with a bit of adhseive so it seals it from the elements and looks tidy

Answer (score 2):

Just cut off the bit if you don't need it. How do you plan on securing the grommet to the wall if you remove the bit?

Comment: The one on the wall doesnt have that part, so guessing its sold without it. I dont need it as I cant rewire the whole thing - I just need to get it cut it around it covered with a bit of adhseive so it seals it from the elements and looks tidy

Comment: I second that the bit that sticks into the wall is to help hold the grommet into place, not guide the wire.